# Servlet throwing exception on deploying on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I was developing an application of counter below is the structure of my application..

first the listener class

```
    package com.saral;

import javax.servlet.*;

public class AppListener implements ServletContextListener
{
ServletContext ctx;
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e)
{
ctx=e.getServletContext();
ctx.setAttribute("hitCount",new Integer(0));
}
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e)
{}
}
```

then filter class..

```
    package com.saral;

import javax.servlet.*;

public class CounterFilter implements Filter
{
ServletContext ctx;
public void init(FilterConfig config){
ctx=config.getServletContext();
}
public void destroy(){}
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain)
{
try
{
Integer ct=(Integer)ctx.getAttribute("hitCount");
int c=ct.intValue();
c++;
ctx.setAttribute("hitCount",new Integer(c));
chain.doFilter(request,response);
}catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
}
}
```

followed by login servlet..

```
    package com.saral;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
{
try{
String name=request.getParameter("txtName");
String pass=request.getParameter("txtPass");
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from logininfo where username=? and password=?");
stmt.setString(1,name);
stmt.setString(2,pass);
ResultSet rset=stmt.executeQuery();
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
if (rset.next())
{
request.getSession().setAttribute("username",name);
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("aa");
rd.forward(request,response);
}
else
{
System.out.println("in else");
out.println("<b>Invalid user name or password.</b><br>");
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("home.html");
rd.include(request,response);
}
out.close();
con .close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
}
}
```

followed by servlet2..

```
package com.saral;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ServletTwo extends HttpServlet
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
{
HttpSession ses=request.getSession();
String name=(String)ses.getAttribute("username");
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.println("welcome,"+name);
out.println("<br> <a href=viewServlet>View Hit Count</a>");
out.close();
}
}
```

and finally view servlet..

```
package com.saral;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ViewServlet extends HttpServlet
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
{
ServletContext ctx=getServletContext();
int c=((Integer)ctx.getAttribute("hitCount")).intValue();
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.println("hit count is:"+c);
out.close();
}
}
```

I have written the web.xml in this way..

```
    <web-app>

<listener>
<listener-class>AppListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
<filter-name>counter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.saral.CounterFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>counter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.saral.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>driverClass</param-name>
<param-value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>connectionString</param-name>
<param-value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>userName</param-name>
<param-value>saral</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>password</param-name>
<param-value>saral</param-value>
</init-param>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>two</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.saral.ServletTwo</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>two</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/aa</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>three</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.saral.ViewServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>three</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/viewServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and my main html is ..

```
<html>
<head>
<title> A Simple web Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="loginServlet">
Name<input type="text" name="txtName"/>
Password<input type="password" name="txtPass"/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But upon deploying this application on tomcat 7 it throws the error..

```
NFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
15 Jul, 2012 12:05:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class AppListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AppListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15 Jul, 2012 12:05:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
15 Jul, 2012 12:05:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
15 Jul, 2012 12:05:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Counter] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Please advise what is wrong in the application

Done this changes as suggested in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.saral.AppListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

but still getting error..

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.saral.AppListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.saral.AppListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15 Jul, 2012 12:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

Please advise

Answer (score 3):

In your web.xml, you have this configuration for listener

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>AppListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The class `AppListener` can't be found, you have to set the full name (including package name):

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.saral.AppListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: the main cause which I think is I am missing some jars..!!

Comment: @user1508454: You may still get *an* error, but it's unlikely to be the *same* error.

Comment: Maybe you had both errors but the Listener was the first (and the only one) throwed when you post the question. Make sure to read the stacktrace to see the error you're fighting.

Comment: @JonSkeet please advise how to overcome from this..!!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza please advise how to overcome from this as I am stuck up.

Comment: @user1508454: Fix the error as shown by Luiggi, then edit your question showing the updated error. Also, you should try to get one servlet working at a time - did you really not try anything until you'd created *all* these servlets?

Comment: @JonSkeet , I have already done the changes as suggested by Luiggi and after that Still I am getting the error, I am not able to open the page mentioned in welcome file list

Comment: @user1508454 the basic way to work is to first make the servlet work, then keep adding new components and check that everything works. Based in the update you wanted to do on my post, maybe your project didn't have the jars to be deployed on a web container.

Comment: @user1508454: Well it certainly sounds like Tomcat now can't see your listener class despite the correct name. Unfortunately, you haven't told us *anything* about how you're deploying the code. I would really start from scratch with *one* dummy servlet and maybe *one* listener. Get those working first.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah you are right a new application also showing the same error, listerner class is not found

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza could you please list the jars , I am using eclipse and in configure build path I have added the tomcat 7 libraries in my build path do I need any more jars despite of that